# Convert Json Data to XML in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, json, xml, laravel-5

I have an Laravel 5.4 Framework.I am going to send Json Request (in Controller) using Post Method.I would like to know how to how to convert Json Data to XML Data in Laravel

I have tried below code but its not working

```
public function store(Request $Request)
{     
    echo json_decode($Request); 


}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30556366/laravel-json-to-xml see this

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this its just an example

```
$age = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
$root=null;
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($root ? '<' . $root . '/>' : '<root/>');
    array_walk_recursive($age, function($value, $key)use($xml){
        $xml->addChild($key, $value);
    });
    echo $xml->asXML();
```

In your case : json_decode outputs array

```
public function store(Request $Request)
{     
    $data=json_decode($Request); 
$root=null;
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($root ? '<' . $root . '/>' : '<root/>');
    array_walk_recursive($data, function($value, $key)use($xml){
        $xml->addChild($key, $value);
    });
    echo $xml->asXML();
}
```

Comment: I have tried above code but its shows an compile error message as "SimpleXMLElement" not found in controller.

Comment: sorry,I have fixed that above issues...but again another issue "ErrorException: array_walk_recursive() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in file"

Comment: just make sure $data varriable is an array